# File for a Logo

Tags: vector

I purchased a logo from Fiverr. The images came in jpg and png. I was told these were not suitable. I questioned the man and he sent 5 formats in a zip file.

I tried to open them but needed to pay a subscription to Adobe.

He is saying that the files are ai ,eps and pdf are high quality files you can confirm from any other designer also at google?

I need the logo for business.

Are these files he has sent me suitable?

Kind Regards

firstfemale

Comment: `.ai` file is enough for you. It's the source file (vector file) and requires Adobe Illustrator to open. You can resize it as you like, you can export it to different other formats. So in sure Yes these files are suitable for you.

Comment: To be honest you get what you pay for. Quite clearly you also needed a consultancy on how to use said files in X, Y and Z which are clearly not some tasks that people on fiverr would provide for you. Therefore you should have paid for said skill transfer too. Because knowing what you need is hard to fish out of a email you would need to talk to a local designer to clear this up.

Comment: You can open the PDF in Adobe Reader which is free - in fact even AI's can also be opened in Adobe Reader, most of the time. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

The .PDF file will open in Adobe Reader (which is free) or even Preview on a Mac...

.ai, .eps. and .pdf are formats *which support* high quality, vector artwork. But then, they also support low resolution raster artwork.

It is entirely possible that the .ai, .eps, and .pdf files are no better than the jpg or png you received. It would be *very unusual* for someone designing a logo to NOT send high quality vector artwork in an .ai or .eps format. But it is not impossible either. The only difference between the suffixes is that png and jpg simply *do not* support high quality vector artwork.

**Very** little can be definitively stated based solely on file suffixes. It **is** an *absolute* that png and jpg do not support vector artwork, but other than that... it's impossible to tell without examining the files.

Comment: Most probably you can also open the ai in a PDF viewer.